# Custom field not returned via Item API

Tags: sitecore-services-client

I am using the Sitecore Item Rest API and all the existing fields (both standard and custom) I need to use from the template come back fine (e.g: `Start Date` below). However I've added a new one (a droplist field) and it is not returned by the API. E.g this is the request: `/sitecore/api/ssc/item/%7bA3FE61CA-82F1-43EE-BA6A-5C923FD81639%7d/children?includeStandardTemplateFields=true`

```
{
    "ItemID": "2cdd1808-31c2-4c88-8b11-39bb8526a033",
    "ItemName": "Adams Test",
    "TemplateName": "Template 1 Test",
    "__Updated": "20170713T100944Z",
    "Start Date": "20170302T104743Z"
},
```

It's very strage as other custom fields are returned. Is there some config I'm missing somewhere to register my new custom field? Is the Item API Powered by Solr in the back ground and I need to update the search config or indexing?

Comment: did you try prefixing database name and field-name in the query?

Comment: Have tried specifying payload=full in the query string?

Comment: I've tested your request and it does return all my custom fields. Have you checked if user has access rights to the field, if the value is set in the context language, if all the necessary things are published?

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas. In the end this looks to have been a publishing issue with the template used. It's now resolved though.

Comment: @AdamSeabridge you should add and accept that as an answer :)  I had the same issue after thinking I had definitely published everything.  I switched to web database and found my field wasn't there - so had to delete and then republish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in my case was a publishing issue. Make sure you double-check that the template(s) your item(s) uses has made it to the Web database. If it isn't there then try re-publishing and check again. The Item Rest API uses the context database for the logged in user so if the content user is using the web database it won't return the item(s).